# How to use sed ssh to change value

Tags: linux, ssh

i need to change value in file with ssh command sed.

```
<serverport>SOMERANDOMNUMBER</serverport>
```

I need to change '22127' to '22222'.

Comment: What is the question?  What have you tried?

Comment: tried this: ssh2_exec($prisijungimas, "sed -i 's/<serverport>([0-9]*\)</serverport>/<serverport>".$sd[0]['port']."</serverport>\1/' /home/".$sd[0]['port']."/mods/deathmatch/mtaserver.conf");

Comment: What's the reason you can't just use something like nano etc ?

Comment: because i'm executing everything in PHP by SSH

Comment: And why would you do that, PHP has access to the filesystem ?

Comment: lol, i'm executing command to REMOTE SERVER.

Comment: So you're using an extension for PHP to do SSH to a remove server then ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try doing this :

```
sed -i.bak 's@<serverport>[0-9]\+</serverport>@<serverport>22222</serverport>@' file
```

But if it's XML, better use [xmlstarlet](/questions/tagged/xmlstarlet)

Comment: i forgot to say, that i don't know what number is written exactly in that file. I'm using PHP SSH.